# git send-email --in-reply-to failed

Tags: linux-kernel, git-send-email

I encounterd the error as below. Can anyone help with this?

```
git send-email  --in-reply-to=CANn89iJCDYteM_1SQ-h2=htUAE4FqrBAak0kHt_Z990XYZThzQ@mail.gmail.com    --to=edumazet@google.com     --cc=davem@davemlof
t.net     --cc=dhowells@redhat.com     --cc=fw@strlen.de     --cc=johannes@sipsolutions.net     --cc=keescook@chromium.org     --cc=kuba@kernel.org     --cc=kuniyu@amazon.com     --cc=linux
-kernel@vger.kernel.org     --cc=netdev@vger.kernel.org     --cc=pabeni@redhat.com     --cc=pctammela@mojatatu.com     --cc=xqjcool@gmail.com reply
reply
No subject line in reply? at /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email line 720.
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're missing a `--subject=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I missed the "Subject:" part in my reply content.

Below is the offical note:

Be sure your reply has a Subject: header at the top and a blank line before the message body.